# Backbone.js Get First Element from JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, json, backbone.js, inline

while I figured out how to get the all of the elements from an array, I am stuck on trying to get an element belonging to the first. I am using Backbone.js and trying to edit one of my templates. The track information I am getting is coming from a JSON file. Can I do this within my HTML file or must I edit my .js file?

HTML:

```
    <script type="text/template" id="lesson-template">
         <span class="lesson-title"><%= title %></span>
         <select class="sel">
            <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %> //this lets me loop through each of them
              <option value = "<%= track.text %>" ><%= track.title %></option>
          <% }); %>        
          </select>
//Now I want to figure out a way to just get the track.text of the first track here and put it in tracktext! 
          <p id="tracktext">Hello World!</p>
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p id="tracktext"><%=  tracks[0].text %></p>
```

You don't appear to be using backbone collections or models here. Is this just a question about javascript and underscore templates perhaps?

Comment: Yes, that is in my JS file. But, yes the question is about javascript; I am a beginner. Thank you!

Comment: One quick question, however, could you explain how <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %> works?

Comment: Here's the annotated source. http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/docs/underscore.html#section-15 In short, it uses a basic javascript for loop to access each element of the array in order, and for each element, it invokes the function you provide, passing the current element as an argument to your function.